# CSS - different behavior same computed styles, overriding bootstrap, body tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Its producing smaller font size when I am using bootstrap followed by my old css file.

Exact declaration for font, in my style sheet is: **font-size: 0.8em;**

bootstrap css is getting bundled but I am manually including my css file in layout page(asp.net mvc) after the bundled styles are rendered. As you can see from below computed styles my css is definitely overriding bootstrap css. but the output is different.

**Without bootstrap**(computed)

```
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
body - 0.8em
```

**With bootstrap** (computed)

```
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 8px;
body - 0.8em
```

**below are struck through in With bootstrap (computed)**

```
body - 14px
html - 62.5%
```

Comment: What are your font-size declarations in your 'old' css file? Sounds like something is overriding bootstrap. Are you using ems/rems?

Comment: Paulie_d: updated my question with info, thanks..

Comment: Are you loading the bootstrap.css file after you load your style.css file?

Comment: lowkase: updated my question with more info, thanks.